# For loop in python - beginner

Tags: python

I'm trying to solve a project where i have to count the years in a list but I`m having problems understanding the difference between

```
years = [n[1] for n in data]
```

and

```
for n in data:
         years = n[1]
```

here is the rest of the body

```
for m in years:
    if m not in year_counts:
        year_counts[m] = 0
    year_counts[m] += 1

print(year_counts)
```

So if I use the first sentence then the code will run normally and will show the proper answer but if i use the second code it will give me random numbers I don't know from where.

Comment: What does the data in `years` look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`years = [n[1] for n in data]` - years is now a list, each element is index [1] of an element in data

`for n in data:
         years = n[1]`

years is a single object and is always updated with n[1] and will finally be index [1] of the last element in data

Comment: Might be helpful to show `data = ['1922', '1999', '2017']`, and that `years` will either be `['9', '9', '0']` or `'0'`

Answer (score 0):

This code `years = [n[1] for n in data]` output is list. 
This code

```
for n in data:
     years = n[1]
```

output is a single variable that contains last value.

Answer (score 0):

In

```
for n in data:
         years = n[1]
```

`years` will be replaced for each n[1](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html).  The "random" entry you are seeing is probably the second letter of the last entry in data.

You could do this instead to match the comprehension:

```
years = list()
data = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4']
for n in data:
  years.append(n[1])  # years = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

but

```
years = [n[1] for n in data]
```

will tend to be faster overall.

For your overall script, you might consider a using [map](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html).

Comment: I see. so years = [n[1] for n in data]  could be translated to years = []
for n in data:
    years.append(n[1])

Comment: Right.  But loops are slower than list comprehensions in general.

Answer (score 0):

```
li = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
# For loop uses for list iteration.
# for loop iterate every item in a list.

for i in li: 
    print i

>>> 1
>>> 2
>>> 3
>>> 4
>>> 5
>>> 6
>>> 7
```